# Assign a thread to each section in an ini file

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, python-multithreading, sections

I am using this toolkit: https://github.com/Fire30/Fifa14Client in python 2.7

```
from Fifa14Client import LoginManager
from Fifa14Client import WebAppFunctioner
import ConfigParser
from extra import EAHash
import threading


def do_main():
    Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    Config.read("accounts_example.ini")
    for section in Config.sections():
        email = Config.get(section, 'Email')
        password = Config.get(section, 'Password')
        secret_answer = Config.get(section, 'Secret')
        security_hash = EAHash.EAHashingAlgorithm().EAHash(secret_answer)
        platform = Config.get(section, 'Platform')

        login = LoginManager.LoginManager(email,password,security_hash,platform)
        login.login()
        func = WebAppFunctioner.WebAppFunctioner(login)
```

What this part of my script does is access an ini file with the login details of accounts for a website and logs in. There are seperate sections, each with their own accounts in the ini file which look like this:

**[AccountOne]**

Email:xxx@xxx.com

Password:qwerty123

Secret:answer

Platform:xbox

**[AccountTwo]**

Email:xxx@xxx.com

Password:qwerty123

Secret:answer

Platform:xbox

And so on. What I want to do is assign a thread to each account so each of them has a separate thread

Sorry if I'm being a little unclear and thanks in advance

Comment: Well, looks like you know you need  the `threading` module. Have you tried actually using it in your code? If so can you share what you've tried?

Comment: I've assigned the accounts to one thread, but the problem is that they all get assigned to just one thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) for this:

```
from Fifa14Client import LoginManager
from Fifa14Client import WebAppFunctioner
import ConfigParser
from extra import EAHash
import threading


def login_thread(email, password, security_hash, platform):
    # This function runs in a separate thread.
    login = LoginManager.LoginManager(email,password,security_hash,platform)
    login.login()
    func = WebAppFunctioner.WebAppFunctioner(login)
    # Do more stuff here

def do_main():
    Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    Config.read("accounts_example.ini")
    threads = []
    for section in Config.sections():
        email = Config.get(section, 'Email')
        password = Config.get(section, 'Password')
        secret_answer = Config.get(section, 'Secret')
        security_hash = EAHash.EAHashingAlgorithm().EAHash(secret_answer)
        platform = Config.get(section, 'Platform')
        t = threading.Thread(target=login_thread, 
                             args=(email, password, security_hash, platform))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads: # Wait for all the threads to finish
        t.join()
```

Keep in mind that because of the [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-a-global-interpreter-lock-gil/1294402#1294402), threads in Python cannot run concurrently across CPU cores, so you won't achieve true parallelism. To get that, you should use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library, which has an API almost identical to `threading`, but isn't limited by the GIL; it uses sub-processes for parallelism, rather than threads. The only change required in the above code to make the switch would be to use `multiprocessing.Process` instead of `threading.Thread`.